# How to get previous to previous URL in Classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have submission form developed in Classic ASP. How to get the 2nd previous visited URL through ASP code? I cannot use query string option as i have embedded the form in SP2013 web page. 
Any suggestions/help?

Comment: `request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")`  will give you the url of the page from which the user arrived, and it should be easy enough for you to use this to populate a hidden form field.  I don't think there's a way of going back two pages, other that by using javascript to look at your browser history

Comment: Like @John say's there is nothing stopping you using `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")`. You could then keep adding to a `Session` variable a delimited list of URLs or store an `Array`. You might want to limit the number of entries though but that gives you a simple enough starting point.

Comment: In fact thinking about it you don't even need to use `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")` you could just have a `#include` file that updates a `Session` variable which then gives you a breadcrumb for every page you have the `#include` file included in.

Comment: For a similar problem, I stored it in a cookie.

Comment: @Vixed It's the same thing at the end of the day Classic ASP `Session` objects are stored in session cookies. The advantage of using your own cookie is it can persist for longer.

Comment: @Lankymart just delete it after the redirect ;)

Comment: @Vixed: Why bother? Just use a Session.

Comment: @Paul are you a squanderer or what?! Tell me why I have to store a session for each user on my server while I can put it on a client pc! 
This explanation is the same for ASP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339783/what-is-the-difference-between-sessions-and-cookies-in-php

Comment: @Vixed: There's an overhead either way. If you put it in a cookie you have  a speed overhead. If you put it on the server you have a memory overhead.  The choice is yours.

Comment: @Vixed: [This is an interesting discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240556/when-should-i-use-session-variables-instead-of-cookies) on when to use which.